# Chrome Extensions and CSP

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I have a popular Chrome Extension that fails on sites using [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP).

The extension enriches content on the sites my users visit, according to some settings they have configured.

On sites with a CSP policy, I get the following error when executing JS: `This document requires 'TrustedScriptURL' assignment`

How can I run my extension on these sites - can I use the site's CSP f.ex., or would that be bad practice?

Comment: If your extension injects a `<script>`, then the site's CSP headers will prevent it from loading if it is not trusted. That's kind-of the whole point behind CSP; if it could be easily circumvented, it would be useless.

Comment: @Pointy aren't the CSP headers supposed to prevent malicious attacks and not limit the user to do as wanted/needed (which is the case for a Chrome Extension)?

Comment: https://www.namogoo.com/privacy-security/how-browser-extensions-routinely-bypass-a-content-security-policy/

Comment: The browser cannot tell the difference about where the injected script tags come from.

Comment: Just make your own trustedTypes policy for createScript as shown in the documentation for trusted types.

Answer (score 0):

Better than never. In MV3, Chrome provides a declarativeNetRequest API that allows you to change the request headers (response and request). More - [declarativeNetRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/). For example, this rule disables CSP completely (removes the CSP header) for incoming requests:

```html
//manifest.json
...
  "permissions": [
    "declarativeNetRequest", 
    "declarativeNetRequestWithHostAccess", 
    "declarativeNetRequestFeedback",
    "scripting",
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "declarative_net_request": {
    "rule_resources": [
      {
        "id": "ruleset_1",
        "enabled": true,
        "path": "rules.json"
      }
    ]
  }
...
//rules.json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "priority": 1,
    "action": {
      "type": "modifyHeaders",
      "responseHeaders": [
        {"header": "Content-Security-Policy", "operation": "remove"}
      ]
    },
    "condition": {
      "urlFilter": "|http*",
      "resourceTypes": ["script", "main_frame", "sub_frame"]
    }
  }
]
```

**Be careful! Your goal is not to disable the CSP, but to set it up so that your content can be loaded/executed.**

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you can try this

```html
<meta
    http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
    content=" default-src 'self' http://* https://*;
  connect-src 'self' http://* https://*; 
  img-src 'self' http://* https://*;"
  />
```

Comment: I don't think I can inject this without using JS, which requires me to fix this problem first? Or am I missing something?